# How to access a file in the jar package in mapper?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

In my map-reduce program, the mapper needs to access a small txt file. I pack this file in my job jar file, so theoretically when the jar file gets extracted on each node (mapper or reducer), the mapper should have access to it. But how can I tell the mapper that the file exists locally?

Comment: Did  you try getResourceAsStream ()?

Comment: no, could you explain it more?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java